# Can't use max resolution for external monitor “xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed”

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have a 1440p monitor connected to my laptop via a HDMI cable and I can't set it to the max. resolution, it only stays at 2048x1080 (9:5).
I have tried using the code below to set the max. resolution:

```
cvt 2560 1440
#Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-2 2560x1440_60.00


xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

What can I do to resolve this?

```
Monitor: dell u2719d
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
GPU: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
```

```
 xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3968 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+2048+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 connected primary 2048x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2048x1080     60.00*   24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: Can you update your original question with the complete results of just running  `xrandr` to me `HDMI-1-2` does not look right, in all my setups it's always been `HDMI-1`, `HDMI-2` etc. But maybe Nvidia setups list them like that. Hence why I was asking for the output of `xrandr`

Comment: Also you could try `cvt -r 2560 1440` to generate a slightly different modeline with reduced dotclock timing.

Comment: Hi codlord, I edited in my ```xrandr``` results as requested. I also tried running the code with ```cvt -r 2560 1440``` instead and it worked! Thank you so much! I will now work on making this script auto run every time I start ubuntu.

I've just started using ubuntu last Monday since I want to move away from microsoft, but I almost gave up on it due to the resolution issue, but you've changed my mind!

Comment: See here for details of how to permanently add undetected resolutions. I have not tried it myself so may or may not work with latest Ubuntu, but regardless the page is a good resource: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Permanently_adding_undetected_resolutions

Answer (score 1):

so as codlord suggested, just using `cvt -r 2560 1440` instead of `cvt 2560 1440` fixed the issue.